# Easier way to generate paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Songs on [Rap Genius](http://rapgenius.com) have paths like `/lyrics/The-notorious-b-i-g-ft-mase-and-puff-daddy/Mo-money-mo-problems` which are defined in `routes.rb` as:

```
map.song '/lyrics/:artist_slug/:title_slug', :controller => 'songs', :action => 'show'
```

When I want to generate such a path, I use `song_url(:title_slug => song.title_slug, :artist_slug => song.artist_slug)`. However, I'd much prefer to be able to type `song_url(some_song)`. Is there a way I can make this happen besides defining a helper like:

```
  def x_song_path(song)
    song_path(:title_slug => song.title_slug, :artist_slug => song.artist_slug)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of defining two slugs you could just have one that has both the title and artist as part of it. So your route would be:

```
map.song '/lyrics/:slug', :controller => 'songs', :action => 'show'
```

Then in your model define a to_param that returns the slug:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    artist.gsub(/\W+/, '-') + '/' + title.gsub(/\W+/, '-')
  end
end
```

I'm not completely sure if that will work (it might try to encode the "/" although if you change the route to

```
map.song '/lyrics/*:slug', :controller => 'songs', :action => 'show'
```

you might be able to get around that. Hopefully that at least gives you ideas of the right place to look.